# Specification of logical node (with distribution?) in WINBUGS

Tags: self-study, prior, bugs

For a piece of homework I have an assignment using WINBUGS which I must admit confuses me to say the least.

Tangential to my question but I have a few stochastic nodes that are to be gamma distributed. Taking one example, the parameters of the gamma distributions (call `a` and `b`) also feed in to lambda which we know the prior distribution for.

```
d ~ gamma(a, b)
z = a/b ~ gamma(0.01, 0.01)
w = b/a ~ gamma(0.01, 0.01)
```

At first look I thought `z` and `w` should be specified as a logical node but then I can't add the distribution information (gamma).

My code runs along these lines (although I've tried numerous versions):

```
d ~  dgamma(a, b)
z ~  dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
w ~  dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
a <- z*b
b <- a/z
a <- b/w
b <- a*w
```

But then I get errors along the lines of "multiple definitions of node...", if I remove one of each of the assignments for `a` and `b` to resolve the multiple definitions, WINBUGS stops responding.

Would really appreciate any words of wisdom of where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user39754. This may be a logical / conceptual issue that we can help you with. However, be aware that if you only need someone to debug your code, that would be off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: How can a/b ~ gamma and b/a ~ gamma? Isn't the inverse of a gamma the inverse gamma distribution?

Comment: In BUGS you can define variable only once, so defining `a <-` and `b <-` twice produces error. Also `a <- z*b` and `b <- a/z` are circular, you need only one of these definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Your model definition is incorrect. In BUGS you can define variable only once, so defining `a <-` and `b <-` twice produces error.

Notice that what your model definition says is that

```
z ~  dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
w ~  dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
d ~  dgamma(a, b)
```

but the problematic part is `a` and `b`, because they are defined circularly

```
d ~  dgamma(a, a/z) # 1
```

and

```
d ~  dgamma(b/w, b) # 2
```

and

```
d ~  dgamma(z*b, b) # 3
```

and

```
d ~  dgamma(a, a*w) # 4
```

If `a` comes from `b`, then `b` cannot come from `a` because the relation is circular. Also notice that `#1` and `#3`, `#2` and `#4` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The `multiple definitions of node` error comes about from you defining `a` and `b` twice.

I strongly suspect that WinBUGS can not handle either of your possible `a` and `b` assignments as `a` involves `b` and `b` involves `a`. I have never seen prior distributions as you have them, but WinBUGS might be able to calculate `a` or `b` if you either 1) define one or both of them in the data or 2) make one or both of them stochastic.